# MOV vs MVI in SAP 2

Tags: assembly, mov

it is written that `mov` is used to transfer data between register and `mvi` is used to transfer an immediate data to register. But why some people also write `mov A,22h`for example even though 22h is an immediate value. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it might be possible to do so - And it is a service of the assembler that relieves you of having to think about whether to use mov or mvi - The assembler sees an immediate value on a mov and generates an mvi.

A lot of assemblers have services like that to make the instruction set more orthogonal. Check your assembler manual to see if it is allowed with yours.